# Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception Error #0

Tags: zend-framework, exception, ssl

I use the Zend libray, especially Loader class. But I take the following exception:

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception' with message 'Unable to Connect to ssl://www.googleapis.com:443. Error #0:
```

I should say that when I run my code local, I don't face any problem, but the exception show when I try to run my file in server. The server I use has ssl security. Is there any possibility to there is any conflict with it?

Comment: have you checked php extension php_openssl is enabled on server ??

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry for asking but I have very little experience to do that.

Comment: location your php.ini , for that do phpinfo(); and then simply uncomment the line whith txt openssl

Comment: I find it and it is already uncommented, so It is enable....

Comment: Is your server allowed to make outbound HTTP connections? i.e. does this work from the command line: wget https://www.googleapis.com

Comment: @EviGreece- Hi, I am also facing the problem with same issue, does this issue resolved for you?

Comment: @MrCoder- On my server php_openssl is enabled then also i am facing the same. Any other suggestions plz?

Answer (score 0):

This error may be caused by SSL level error like untrusted/expired SSL certificate which can be caused by wrong local system date.

Answer (score 0):

If you on Ubuntu try add in your `php.ini`

```
openssl.capath=/etc/ssl/certs
```

[For more info read this issue](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/issues/2535)